# VC++ 2013: using-declaration + redefinition of member function leads to compile error

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2013

I want to allow to modify behaviour of my class by specifing policy. This policy shoud be used as visitor for boost::variant. There is default policy that fits most cases good, but user may need to add or replace some overloads.

I found that vc++ 2013 doesn't compile this code with error `C3066: there are multiple ways that an object of this type can be called with these arguments`. Same code compiles and works as expected in gcc and clang.

Is it vc++ 2013 bug?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct DefaultPolicy
{
    void operator()( bool ) { std::cout << "Base: bool" << std::endl; }
    void operator()( int ) { std::cout << "Base: int" << std::endl; }
};

struct UserModifiedPolicy : public DefaultPolicy
{
    using DefaultPolicy::operator();
    void operator()( int ) { std::cout << "Derived: int" << std::endl; }
    void operator()( float ) { std::cout << "Derived: float" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    UserModifiedPolicy()(true);
    UserModifiedPolicy()(1); // <-- ERROR HERE
    UserModifiedPolicy()(1.f);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPD** This exaple works in vc++ 2010. Looks like it is a bug in 2013 version.

---

**UPD** Workaround

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct DefaultPolicy
{
    void operator()( bool ) { std::cout << "Base: bool" << std::endl; }
    void operator()( int ) { std::cout << "Base: int" << std::endl; }
};

struct UserModifiedPolicy : public DefaultPolicy
{
    // Using template to forward a call to the base class:
    template< class T >
    void operator()( T && t ) { DefaultPolicy::operator()( std::forward<T>(t) ); }

    void operator()( int ) { std::cout << "Derived: int" << std::endl; }
    void operator()( float ) { std::cout << "Derived: float" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    UserModifiedPolicy()(true);
    UserModifiedPolicy()(1);
    UserModifiedPolicy()(1.f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which call generates the error?

Comment: What version of vc++ ?

Comment: UserModifiedPolicy()(1); // error here (int overload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is well-formed.  7.3.3/15:

> When a *using-declaration* brings names from a base class into a derived class scope, member functions and member function templates in the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member function templates with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and *ref-qualifier* (if any) in a base class (rather than conflicting).

So `UserModifiedPolicy::operator()(int)` should still hide `DefaultPolicy::operator()(int)`.  And name lookup for `operator()` should find the three members `DefaultPolicy::operator()(bool)`, `UserModifiedPolicy::operator()(int)`, and `UserModifiedPolicy::operator()(float)`.