# Why does VC++2013 refuse to compile nested types, made visibile with the using keyword, when used as a template functions return type?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, nested, multiple-inheritance

Visual Studio 2013 (update 2) throws a compile-time error when compiling a template function who's return type is a nested type name, which has been hidden through multiple inheritance, and made visible again with the `using` keyword; as in the following code:

```
struct Base1
{
  typedef int value_type;
};

struct Base2
{
  typedef double value_type;
};

struct Derived : Base1, Base2
{
  using Base1::value_type;
};

template<typename T>
typename T::value_type nullary_function() { return 0; }

template<typename T>
typename T::value_type unary_function(T t) { return 0; }

int main()
{
  nullary_function<Derived>(); // Error: C2770
  unary_function( Derived() ); // Error: C2893
  return 0;
}
```

(The error numbers vary depending upon whether the function accepts template arguments or not as shown in the comments.)

G++ 4.7 accepts this code.

Specifically, I would like to know what the C++ standard has to say on the matter and whether or not this is a VC++ compiler bug. (It would appear to me that it is seeing as making nested types visible with the `using` keyword makes them visible in every other situation as far as I'm aware.)

I am also aware that the line with the `using` keyword may be changed from

```
using Base1::value_type;
```

to

```
typedef Base1::value_type value_type;
```

in order to get the code to compile and function correctly, but it seems bad for portability for some (potentially) valid code to compile on some compilers and not others - hence the desire for clarification.

Comment: "it seems bad for portability" - a cynic might point out that it could be in a platform vendor's interest for code written for their platform not to be portable. But I'm sure there's a perfectly innocent reason for this compiler's idiosyncratic interpretation of the language.

Comment: The latest update is completely broken in my experience. Template deductions that worked previously now crashes the compiler!

Comment: FWIW, I've had a few issues with the `using` vs. `typedef` with VS2013, they seem to not have worked all the issues out. File it as a bug on the MS Connect website and go on with the `typedef` until they fix it. You could try VS2013 update 3, the support is better but it may still not work.

Comment: In `typedef typename Base1::value_type value_type;` you don't need `typename` since `Base1` is not dependant

Comment: Just checked, same errors on VS2013.3. Stick to the `typedef`.

Comment: @Antoine - Just noticed that myself. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Niall - Yeah I was planning to submit a bug for it; just wanted to get some confirmation that I'm not being an idiot first seeing as most compiler errors aren't! :)

Comment: Checked with VS2010 and VS2012; Exactly the same errors - Definitely not a new problem!

Comment: This has been submitted as a bug; [bug report here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/968574)

Comment: I met similar (but not the same) [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409307/vc-2013-using-declaration-redefinition-of-member-function-leads-to-compile)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a compiler bug -- ICC, CLang, and G++ all accept this code as verified on [Godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org).

The most applicable language in the standard I could find is 7.3.3 (namespace.udecl) p2 (quoted from [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf))

> Every *using-declaration* is a *declaration* and a *member-declaration* and so can be used 
>   in a class definition.

P.S. ICC, CLang, and G++ all accept the typedef version as well.